# how to remove slashes and quotes from a string literal in c#

Tags: c#

A call to an API I have been given is returning the following

"\"Approved\""

In c#, how can I convert this into a normal string?

Comment: Looks like this problem can be solved by [String.Replace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) method. Or it's not your case?

Comment: There are no "slashes", it is just an artifact of the debugger which tries to display the string the way you would write it in your source code.  Use the Text Visualizer to see this for yourself, looks like a spyglass icon in the debugger.  You'll now only see the double-quotes.  Simply use Substring() to filter them.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   var s = "\"Approved\"";

   var r = s.Replace("\"", string.Empty);                  

   Console.WriteLine(r);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried using string replace to no avail.

Here is how i did it eventually, this just strips everything out that isn't a character

```
myString = = new string((from c in hasAccount where char.IsWhiteSpace(c) || char.IsLetterOrDigit(c) select c).ToArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

[String.TrimStart](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimstart(v=vs.110).aspx)

and String.TrimEnd

```
var r=s.TrimStart('"').TrimEnd('"');
```

or probably more appropriate just -
[String.Trim](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d4tt83f9(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
var r=s.Trim('"');
```